# Asymptotic evaluation of a quantity

Tags: asymptotics, lambert-w

Can we say that the following quantity (a recursion of logarithms):

$W_{-1}(x)=\ln \cfrac{-x}{-\ln \cfrac{-x}{-\ln \cfrac{-x}{...}}}$

is $\Theta(\ln x)$? i.e., asimptotically upper and lower bounded?

Comment: Are these minus signs of any use ?

Comment: Yes, the sign - distinguishes this negative branch from the positive branch (in the Lambert function).

Comment: Don't they simplify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual question seems to be about the asymptotics of $W_{-1}(x)$. I'm not sure how the expression for $W_{-1}(x)$ in your question is relevant.

Complete asymptotic expansions for the branches of $W$ were obtained in Corless et. al. "On the Lambert W Function" [[PDF Link]](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf) and Jeffrey et. al. "Unwinding the branches of the Lambert W function" [[HTML link]](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266301429_Unwinding_the_branches_of_the_Lambert_W_functionMath).

In particular, taking only the largest term in the double series in equation (4.19) in the first paper,

\begin{align*}
 W_{-1}(z) &= \log(-x) - \log (-\log(-x)) + \Theta\!\left(\frac{\log(-\log(-x))}{\log(-x)}\right)
\end{align*}

as $x \to 0^-$ with $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Is the last term in the right member a $\theta$ or a small $o$ ? In fact, I need to show that $W_{-1}(-\log^{-c}n)$ is in $\Omega(\log(\log^{-c}n))$, where $c$ is a positive constant. Can we use directly your formula?

Comment: @Dingo13, It's $\Theta$, just as I've written it. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations) for the definition. Using just the first term of the expression I gave, $$W_{-1}(-\log^{-c} n) \sim \log \log^{-c} n \qquad \text{as } n \to \infty,$$ so certainly $W_{-1}(-\log^{-c} n) = \Omega(\log \log^{-c} n)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

At convergence, $$y=\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right),$$ or

$$x=ye^y$$ and $$y=W(x).$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you give more information ?

Comment: @Dingo13: about what ? This is straightforward.

Comment: in fact I don't really understand. You've written a recursive equation $y=\ln(x/y)$. The upper and lower bounds should not depend on $y$? doesn't it? What is the progression in the reasoning?

Comment: @Dingo13: I haven't written any bound, just solved the recurrence.

Comment: You say that $W(x)=W_{-1}(x)$ ? I'm looking for a rough lower and upper bound for $W_{-1}(x)$, using $\Theta$ notation.

Comment: One of $W_0$, $W_{-1}$, I don't know. Have you looked-up Wikipedia ?

Comment: I would like to show that $W_{-1} (x)$ is $\Theta(\ln x)$. Maybe it's obvious, but not so obvious. Yes I've looked-up Wiki and There is informformation for $W_0(x)$, but not in precision for $W_{-1}$.

Comment: Plug your asymptotic formula in $W_{-1}(x)\exp(W_{-1}(x))=x$.

Comment: Is this plug showing what I want ? thanks again.

Comment: If I substitute, I obtain $\Theta(x \ln x)=x$. Curiously, there is a formula on Wiki for $W_0(x)$ suggesting that $W_0(x)=\Theta(\ln x)$. What is the problem ?

Comment: For what values are you considering the asymptotic bounds ?

Comment: this is for negative values, but tending to 0.